# Is it allowed to downvote all your questions?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I opened a question about index.php which can be read here: 
[Many pages handled by single PHP file vs many PHP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282634/whats-the-advantage-of-every-page-on-index-php)

A user called Taxicala answered on me, but he started to insult and said something which looked like: Haven't you learned to read at summercamp? (He said that because another user talked about Templates and according to him I read something particular wrong, but I can't recall what and he removed his comment), and treated me like I was stupid because of my question. I just started learning to build websites 2 weeks ago so how should I already know everything in this stage? I told him that I would downvote his answer if I could because it wasn't useful and respectful.

For some reason nothing was left of his answer and comments and all my questions received a -2 downvote.

Is this allowed at Stackoverflow and am I allowed to downvote all someones questions or is this against the policy?

Comment: No, targeting people with votes (up or down) is not allowed. The system will detect and reverse it. If you're the one doing the voting, a suspension might be the result. See also [What is serial voting and how does it affect me!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) for when you're on the receiving end.

Comment: I see, I didn't want to downvote anyway because that's unfair. But he just could do it and nothing seemed to happen, that's why I asked the question. So he will get problems now? Will my reputation be restored then?

Comment: @Blogger: Your reputation will be restored automatically, after the script runs (usually once a day around 3 am UTC). If the serial voter does this routinely the moderators will have a stern word with them.

Comment: Taxicala deleted his own answer, I can see the answer and some comments, but all comments you mentioned are deleted so only a mod can see them. All in all, I'd just move on.

Comment: If you got -2 on all posts, consider flagging one for diamond moderator attention and describe you suspect sock-puppeting, not only serial voting. Single user can give -1 on all, -2 requires two.

Comment: Not a duplicate, the linked question is about serial-voting, so about downvotes in short period of time. Those question apply also for downvoting in much longer perspective, at least potentially.

Comment: @Mołot I think he's referring to -2 reputation points (which would be a single downvote)

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed everything you think is of poor quality, **except** you aren't allowed to serial-downvote (as well as serial-upvote) single user. The serialvoting reversal scripts runs each day and removes everything he think to be serial voting on single user, but it generally **counts votes from last run**. So downvoting one post a day isn't a serial voting.

Theoretically, it is possible to **downvote all posts** of single user, but if all posts are downvoted by single user, it's very suspicious and you need to have **very good reason** to do something like that, namely, all posts of that user must be really crap.

**Even in such case you should flag for moderator attention!**. Accounts where each post deserves a downvote are a typical case for moderator intervention!

**Revenge downvoting is no-go!** If you will be caught on downvoting because of a user and not because of content, say farewell to your SO account (at least for some time).

In your case, it was quite unclear what you were asking, this could attract downvotes. Normally the people understand problems of new users, especially being not native speakers, with clear formulating, but some are quite intolerant. The answer made the question quite clear, but people reviewing close queue don't see answers, so it's always necessary to write clear. From the title it could be understood you're asking about making sitemap on start page. I hope my edit has helped, but I'm not a native speaker too.

Comment: I see, this guy has a high reputation so I was already hoping the system on StackOverflow is fair and doesn't not punish him because of a high reputation, but seeing as there is a script used his account will probably be suspended.

Comment: @Blogger I don't think a suspension will necessarily happen. Especially not if this would be a first offence. And to be entirely honest, you probably can not be 100% certain it was that particular user who did the voting. The best thing for you to do is to just let it be, and let the system take effect.

Comment: Note that the user only _has_ four questions -- someone might think that all of the questions posted were of low quality, especially when there aren't many questions to begin with. I certainly don't intend to advocate for serial downvoting though.

Comment: All good, but one minor detail I would just caution about; the part where you say it only counts votes from the last run. That may or may not be true, but at minimum is a significant over-simplification.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I know that only such votes are reversed, and if a user is active in niche tag, it's very probable all his/hers posts would be voted (up or down) by some single user. I've never observed reversing the downvotes older as from last run, and I've observed reserval script in action quite often on Area51, where some proposals have often many poor/troll questions from single user one under another :)

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be solved. My question votes got reversed, but it seems like my reputation got higher instead of the same? :S Is this normal when reversing downvoting or is it possible that people have read my questions and some have given votes today which gives a higher result? I 'm not a native English speaker by the way which could have caused my question to be unclear too. I tried to make it clear but it kept being downvoted.

Comment: @Blogger meta posts attracts attention to your posts on other accounts, which may either result in additional upvotes or in additional downvotes ;)

Comment: Ok dzieki Lukasz. Jestesz bardzo pomoc. Sorry, my Polish is not very good.